# Как сделать доступность не только по табу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не используя мышь, по сайту мы можем двигаться с помощью таба (по интерактивным элементам), также мы можем двигаться стрелками по заголовкам, тексту и т.д.

Как сделать так чтобы, при движении стрелками по заголовкам, тексту можно было бы как-то это визуально выделять на странице с помощью интерактивных состояний по типу active, focus, также как мы делаем это для ссылок, кнопок?

Спасибо!

Comment: `как-то` - это как? Сами что пытались делать?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex